# Make visible the article in Draft and Needs Review mode to other members of the community group

Tags: organic-groups, workbench

I am facing a permission issue, I found not yet a resolution.
I am using Workbench, Workbench Moderation and Organic Groups.

User1 creates a content in a community (organic groups)
Then he creates content setting its moderation mode to: Draft

Now User2 ask permission to join group, but he is unable to see the above article until is set to Published mode.

How can they share the article set in Draft mode?

Answer (score 0):

Is the below permissions checked from permission tab ? If it's not then set the below permissions:

Workbench Moderation:

1. View all unpublished content
2. View the moderation messages on a node
3. View moderation history
4. Use "My Drafts" workbench tab
5. Use "Needs Review" workbench tab

Also let me know which version of workbench moderation module you are using .